# Changing a string to smaller one

Tags: string, matlab

I have this string:

```
aa= 'SAN/MOST/MOD10A1.005/2000.02.26/MOD10A1.A2000057.h01v10.005.2007163034521.hdf.xml'
```

I want to change it to:

```
'MOD10A1.A2000057.h01v10.005.2007163034521.hdf.xml'
```

How can i do that by using Matlab??
I try this code but it does not work correctly.

```
s=regexp(aa, '[_.]', 'split');
```

Anybody can help??

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strfind` function instead:

```
idx = strfind(aa,'/');
s = aa(idx(end)+1:end)
```

Answer (score 2):

`strfind` is only available from R2013a and onwards.  You can certainly use `regexp` like you have done before, but look for the `/` symbol instead.  Look for the last occurrence of the `/` symbol, then use that and subset the rest of your string just like what Highman is doing.  In other words:

```
aa = 'SAN/MOST/MOD10A1.005/2000.02.26/MOD10A1.A2000057.h01v10.005.2007163034521.hdf.xml';
idx = regexp(aa, '\/');
aaSubset = aa(idx(end)+1 : end);
```

Take note that I had to use the `\` character and place it before the `/` character as `/` is a reserved symbol when looking at regular expressions.  `aaSubset` contains the string that you're looking for.  I get:

```
aaSubset =

MOD10A1.A2000057.h01v10.005.2007163034521.hdf.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using regular expressions (specifically [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html)):

```
s = regexprep(aa, '^.*\/', '');
```

This [greedily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) looks for any sequence of characters beginning at the start of the string and ending in `/`, and removes that (replaces it by an empty string).

---

You could also use [`fileparts`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html):

```
[folder, name, ext] = fileparts(aa);
s = [name ext];
```

Comment: Wow.  Didn't know about `fileparts`.  Cool!